# Solving linear recurrence equation $x_{n+3}-x_n=2n+3\sin\frac{2n\pi}{3}$

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion, fundamental-solution

I've been trying to solve the following equation

$$x_{n+3}-x_n=2n+3\sin\frac{2n\pi}{3},\ \ n=0,1,\ldots$$
I am looking for my solution in the form of $$x_n=x_n^H+x_n^P$$, that is, as the sum of the homogoneous and particular solution. The homogenous is pretty easy, i have the characteristic equation $\lambda^3-1=0$, from where i get that $$\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda_3=1,$$ and the fundamental set is $$\{1^n,n\cdot 1^n, n^2\cdot 1^n\},$$ and the homogeneous solution is $$x_n^H=c_1+nc_2+n^2c_3.$$
The problem is the particular solution. My question is, do i look for the particualr equation in the following  form $$x_n^p=(An+B)\cdot n^3 + C\sin\frac{2n\pi}{3}+D\cos\frac{2n\pi}{3}?$$

Comment: (Much) simpler: solve separately for $a_n=x_{3n}$, $b_n=x_{3n+1}$ and $c_n=x_{3n+2}$, noting that $$a_{n+1}=a_n+6n\qquad b_{n+1}=b_n+6n+2+3\frac{\sqrt3}2\qquad c_{n+1}=c_n+6n+4-3\frac{\sqrt3}2$$ Can you proceed?

Comment: how did you get that?

Comment: The equation $\lambda^3=1$ doesn't have unique solution $1$ : the solutions are the three third roots of $1$, which are $1$ and $e^{\pm2i\pi/3}$.

Comment: Tell me... Seriously, if $a_n=x_{3n}$ and $a_{n+1}=x_{3n+3}$, can't you relate them?

Comment: Idiot hahah...I get it...thnx